# Java - Why is it allowed to have Variable Name as Type Name

Tags: java, class, naming-conventions

Lets Say I have Class `ClassA`

I can declare a variable as below

```
public ClassA ClassA;
```

**Note**:- Variable name is same as Type Name and 
There is no compilation error.

This can cause confusion when you want to invoke static method

```
ClassA.someStaticMethod();
```

In Above Statement `ClassA` will be treated as instance variable and if it is null then it is impossible to call static method.

Why is it allowed anyway ?

Are there any Use Cases where this may be beneficial?

Comment: inside the class call the static with nothing, outside the class point the name as class name with full name (includes packages)

Comment: I'm confused as to the downvotes; this question wasn't edited and it looks good to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if it is null then it is impossible to call static method.

It *is* possible:

```
public final class Foo
{
    public static void yuck()
    {
        System.out.println("Yuck!");
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        final Foo foo = null;
        foo.yuck(); // compiles, and does the job
    }
}
```

Even though it may seem counterintuitive, the fact is that static methods need only know the *class*; even if an instance of `Foo` is `null`, like in the example above, the JVM knows it is of class `Foo`; `yuck()` being a static method, it does not "dereference" the instance, because it does not need to; therefore, no NPE.

> Why is it allowed?

Because this is a legal Java identifier ([JLS, section 6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.2)). The only restrictions to Java identifiers is that they cannot be keywords.

> Are there any Use Cases where this may be beneficial?

You probably can figure it out for yourself: try as hard as you can('t), I defy you to find one ;)

Comment: Thanks fge as I was not aware of the fact that you can invoke static method with null reference

Comment: The fact that you can invoke static methods from object instances is strange enough :p But it is "too late" now, unless Oracle decides on a Java2 iteration which does not allow it...

Comment: Weirder Thing is that you can do this with null reference which is not 
intuitive

Comment: Edited again, first explanation was confusing